# smtpd_client_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

My problem is my poor server is constantly suffering from attempts to send mail from outside menaces.
There are hundreds of attempts per hour - here is one of them from maillog

```
Aug 15 03:43:17 xxxxxxxx courier-pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:212.142.140.236]
Aug 15 03:43:17 xxxxxxxx courier-authdaemon: authpsa: short mail addresses are not allowed, got 'radiomail'
Aug 15 03:43:17 xxxxxxxx courier-pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=radiomail, ip=[::ffff:212.142.140.236]
Aug 15 03:43:17 xxxxxxxx courier-pop3d: authentication error: Input/output error
```

The IP in question is listed as a menace on Spamhaus, but not on Barracuda, which is what I use. I have reported it to Barracuda.
Luckily it is failing because of 'short email address'.
I want to stop them from all these attempts. I tried putting the IP into a file client_checks.. like this

```
212.142.140.236 REJECT Your IP is spam
```

Then I added a line in main.cf like this

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks
```

result - No Change

Am I putting the test in the wrong section/space?

I noticed that there is a client_restrictions and a sender_restrictions.. here they are

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access, pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org
```

One thing I did spot is a comma after check_client_access and check_sender_access.. is this OK?

Comment: are you mixing up courier and postfix?

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. `smtpd_client_restrictions` is the logical place to put restrictions based on IP address, DNS RBL or similar.  It doesn't require knowledge of sender or recipient, but in practice Postfix doesn't REJECT until the sending server has sent both of these.
2. If you use a `hash:` table, you must remember to create the Postfix hash table, with `postmap /etc/postfix/client_checks`
3. You list log lines from Courier, a POP/IMAP daemon.  Is Postfix using it for authentication?  If not, you might want to look at the postfix log lines for attempted spam instead.
4. You might like to look into fail2ban for automatically firewalling failed POP, IMAP or SMTP attempts.  People have written filters for Courier and Postfix.

Comment: There's a reason to put RBL/blacklist checks in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`: because spam-list providers will ban you for excessive checks, so it's better to run those checks AFTER filtering out unknown hostnames and helo-validity.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I have been researching this 'brute force attack' and have solved the problem from this particular IP (and others) by creating a new rule in my firewall. I can now deny any IP I dont like..
My maillog is now readable and usable, before I couldn't see the wood for the trees.
I can see all my valid users logging in and am thinking of writing something to extract all valid IP addresses and having a 'allow only' type rule too.